# How to download new files in Netbeans FTP view

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp

I have created a new project as a PHP Application from Remote Server. I am using the passive mode FTP connection setting, as without this setting I could not access the files via Netbeans at all. However, some files on the server do not show in my Netbeans panel. **How does one refresh the view to show new files on the server?** I have tried closing and reopening Netbeans, however it seems that Netbeans will only upload, not download new files. I see no obvious menu items for refreshing the view from the server, and adding the Scan on Demand plugin did not help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try right click project > Download?

Comment: Thanks, MeLight. In neither the Projects nor the Files panel do the context menu item "Download" exist.

Comment: Interestingly, the inner folders do have the "Download" menu item, but the Source Files and top-level directories do not! So I can only refresh folders that are at least two levels deep! I'll file an issue at netbeans. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see that option as well. I had that option prior to 7.2 on each folder on my project. I'm able to upload files on save automatically but not able to right click and upload/download a folder manually. UPDATE: Found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, the inner folders do have a "Download" menu item for downloading new and changed files from the server, but the Source Files and top-level directories do not have this item. Therefore the user can only refresh folders that are at least two levels deep.

Answer (score 15):

right click on  ****Source files****  then select :

- **Download** for downloading files.
  or
- **Upload** to upload your local files.
  or
- **Synchronize** to synchronize existing files in local and server.

i hope my answer is useful for you

Comment: Thank you my friend Youssef!

Answer (score 9):

You can find the Upload/Download option on all folders if you are using the Project Tab. The same option does not exist when you are browsing the Files tab. This will solve your issue. Because it worked for me.

Comment: +1 - I was able to get my Project Tab showing again by going to View > Toolbars > Customize. Under the Project folder there was an item named Projects. I dragged that to my toolbar. Then clicked on it to restore the tab.

Answer (score 3):

In 7.2.1, go to projects, expand the project you want to get the files for, then right click on the folder that says 'Source Files' for a download menu item that gets all of your files for that project.

[image]

Comment: P.S. this will detect and download new files on the server as well, so this does indeed answer the question.